# batch file won't exit after completion

Tags: batch-file

I created one batch file, where it calls 2 batch files to execute one task, on completion Windows command prompt will not get exit.

I tried exit in both batch files at bottom line, but doesn't work, because of which log files will not end

```
My Script Sample

CALL ScriptOne

CALL ScriptTwo
```

Thanks,
Satish

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to do. You want call first bat, then second one, then, for some unknown reason, exit? Put exit after last call, but it wouldn't work if you call'ed your initial script.

Comment: First batch file creates one log file after completion of task and second one create another log as well. Here I tried calling exit in second batch file as last line, even though the script do not exit from DOS, and if I press Ctrl+C to exit it, it will not exit and screen execution statements logs in logs file instead of dos screen. I also tried keeping both scripts in one batch but first one executes and ignores second one.

Comment: exit at last line does nothing if you call'd script. It's quite hard to understand you, but as far as i can see - some commands you execute in second bat just didn't finished. Maybe they taking long time, maybe they waiting something to happen - hard to tell what you're doing

Comment: I realized, your right, it get closes itself after complete.

Comment: Add an ECHO statement after each CALL.  As @keltar suggested, 2nd script is probably not finishing.

Comment: Also try starting the batch files instead of calling them. THat way once the original window has exited, if anything else is open, you'll know whats your problem.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the batch file which you want to run add this:

`EXIT`

The batch fill will look like:

```
Some code
EXIT
```